# Execute custom function onChange

Tags: javascript, html, dom

**Pure JavaScript.**

I have a checkbox in HTML page. I want to execute

```
App.setCheckedProperty(name, val);
```

Where `name` is name attribute of the checkbox and `val` true/false means checked.

How to implement it? I can't find any materials aboit it on the Net.

**UPD**:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="smth" onChange="<WHAT TO DO HERE?>" checked />
```

Final execution must be equal:

```
App.setCheckedProperty("smth", false);
```

**UPD2**:

Are there any contructions like `this.name` or `this.checked` in JavaScript?

Comment: It is always helpful to include some code which you have tried that did not work.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't have any code for it - I don't know how to impl it.

Comment: Yes, `this.name` and `this.checked` both exist and both should be passed to your function in `onchange`

Comment: Thanks! Can you format it as an answer for me to make it answered?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, sorry for my broken english. Can you, please, create an Answer here - I want to make this question answered by you.

Comment: @IllyaKovalevskyy See hereandnow78's complete answer below - I don't need to add one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldnt do it "inline" inside your html. its just bad practice. i think what you want to do is to loop over a couple of checkboxes?

see this code:

```
// declare all vars that you need and find all input-elements
var i, input, inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

// loop over all input-elements
for(i = 0; i <= inputs.length; i++) {
  input = inputs[i];

  // if the current element is a checkbox
  if(input.type === 'checkbox') {

    //append a click-handler to that checkbox
    input.onclick = function () {

      // if the checkbox is clicked, you can find the name and the checked-property
      App.setCheckedProperty(this.name, this.checked);
    };   
  }
}
```

and a working example here (i just alert instead of App.setCheckedProperty): http://jsfiddle.net/5wExJ/